# How can I check if an entry exists in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

Given the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
d[1][2].append(3)
```

how do I check `d` to see if it contains an entry for `d[2][3]`, for example?

Comment: Will the number of levels of nesting be the same always?